# Compare 4 float values for the highest value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, floating-point, compare

Having trouble comparing 4 float values in objective c, I would like to return the highest or equal values of these 4 integers. As you can see two are the same here.

This is the NSLOG output

```
2011-08-17 17:17:30.328 [21087:c203] 1 = 6.000000
2011-08-17 17:17:30.328 [21087:c203] 2 = 4.400000
2011-08-17 17:17:30.352 [21087:c203] 3 = 0.000000
2011-08-17 17:17:30.353 [21087:c203] 4 = 6.000000
```

Lets say 1-4

I have tried the MAX(1,2) Statement
Also checked >= value using if and statements too..

I am able to write my own code for comparing the values using an algorythm but I wanted to check to see if there is an easier way to do it and save me some headache??

Perhaps creating a float with a really high value and then comparing which one was the closest to it??

I have tried reading [this site](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm) and its just confusing me

I am kind of new to objective c, have done it for 2 years but still sometimes it stumps you!!

Edit - Solved by brain!..

```
2011-08-18 12:10:26.798 iT[2093:c203] 1 = 6.710000 
2011-08-18 12:10:26.798 iT[2093:c203] 2 = 0.000000 
2011-08-18 12:10:26.799 iT[2093:c203] 3 = 7.000000 
2011-08-18 12:10:26.800 iT[2093:c203] 4 is 9.000000 

float max = MAX(1,MAX(2,MAX(3,4))); NSLog(@"Max is %f", max); 

NSLog Output "Max is 9.000000"
```

Such an easy way to solve it, Brilliant!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems pretty simple to me to just nest the max calls:

```
max(1,max(2,max(3,4)))
```

Where 1,2,3,4 refer to the variable names.

Usually this sort of thing is done over collections, in which case you can so something like this (in pseudocode):

```
float max = Float.Min_Value;
for (float f in float_array) {
    if (f > max) {
        max = f;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Brain, Thank you for your quick reply, I have never used nested calls before, How can I then output the result of the MAX(1,MAX(2,MAX(3,4))); to NSLOG?? Much appreciated

Comment: Max is 9.000000.... brainy you clearly are!!
Much appreciated!!!
`code
    2011-08-18 12:10:26.798 iT[2093:c203] 1 = 6.710000
    2011-08-18 12:10:26.798 iT[2093:c203] 2 = 0.000000
    2011-08-18 12:10:26.799 iT[2093:c203] 3 = 7.000000
    2011-08-18 12:10:26.800 iT[2093:c203] 4 is 9.000000
    float max = MAX(1,MAX(2,MAX(3,4)));
    NSLog(@"Max is %f", max);
`
Cheers - Beej

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean `MAX(MAX(6.0000,4.0000),MAX(0.0000,6.00000))`? this should return 6.0000.

EDIT - some examples:

```
int i = MAX(1,2);
```

in this case i would be set to 2.

```
int j = MAX(MAX(1,2),MAX(3,3));
```

This is simply nesting the functions, so would equate to:

```
MAX(2,3);
```

and j would be set to 3.  As you can see there is no concept of equal values.

HTH Dave

Comment: Hi Beej, MAX is a macro that returns the result.  Have put some more examples in my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much Dave, thats helped me understand a lot more!!
No concept of equal values meaning basically that it would return both of them, just a little bit of leg work my side to compare them then :)
-Beej